# Can't make POST request in my rest service

Tags: java, spring, rest, h2

I have a REST  service  with an embedded H2  database  after  adding  this  configuration  into  application.properties:

```
 hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto
```

I can't make  any  POST  request PROPERLY.

I  don't  receive any errors  WITH POSTMAN  but  when I  make  GET request  I can't  get  any  element ( I MEAN RESPONSE  IS EMPTY []).
 
 What  should  I change   to make it  work?  Should  I  delete  H2  database and  run  this  project  or  is there a more flexible  solution in this case?

Comment: check your log files.  or use a debugger and step through your code to see what's happening

Comment: is there data in your in memory DB which could be returned as result?